# How do you freeze fresh pineapple? Can you?

Tags: freezing, pineapple

I cut the up a fresh pineapple and wanted to freeze a portion, will it last and retain flavor/consistency? Also: is there anything that can be done with the Core - the hard part in the middle?

Comment: I juice the cores in my morning juicer.

Answer (score 6):

I usually cut the pineapple into bite size pieces before freezing them.

1. IF i'm at my mom's restaurant, I usually put it in the super chiller, and then into the freezer.
2. At home, I usually drain it, for 20 -30 minutes in a sieve and then put them in air tight freezer bags.

Answer (score 4):

I cut it into pieces, put it on a cookie sheet, and put it in the freezer of my refrigerator. When it is solid, I put it in bags (1/4 of the pineapple in each) and vacuum seal it. This goes into my chest freezer to enjoy later. If pineapples are a dollar apiece, it only makes sense to freeze them. The cores do make a great ice cream topping if you dice them finely and cook them down in a simple syrup.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice, and thanks for the answer! I think you'll find your answers are better received if you take the time to write them with proper grammar. (I've gone ahead and edited this one for you.)

Answer (score 3):

If you cut the pineapple core into smaller pieces (say, something like a dice), then it's usable.  Cutting against the grain will shorten the overall fibers, too.  Also, I'd be willing to bet that the core pieces could be used for a tasty syrup.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the core and skin (wash the pineapple before you cut it up) to make a great tea - put pieces of skin and core into a medium size sauce pan, add a few slices of fresh ginger, cover with water, simmer an hour and then let sit until it cools. Remove all the solid pieces, pour the liquid into a container. Delicious as a cold drink or heated as a tea - the bromelain in pineapple is a great anti-inflammatory and ginger has beneficial digestive properties.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose pineapple should freeze as well as any other fruit as long as it is done quickly else it might go soft when you defrost it.

If you have a good blender, you can use the whole pineapple (without the skin of course as it is coarse) including the core - it is very healthy as it contains **bromelain** which helps to block excessive coagulation of the blood, reduce inflammation and can reduce the growth of some tumours (from what I have read, I am no doctor so can't say if it is true or not)

Answer (score -2):

I have also heard the core is the most beneficial as it is the part that contains **bromelian**.
After washing then cutting the leaves & the bottom off, I quarter from top to bottom. I then put through the juicer. My grandkids call them smoothies because they are thick & creamy. No one would guess the skin went right in with it also.